# How to apply a validation rule to every element present within an array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

How to apply validation rules to every `item` within an `items[]` array? For example:

```php
...->validate($request, [
    'items[]' => 'required' // <-- what is the correct syntax?
]);
```

Comment: is it possible to name the fields with the same name for example `email` like `email.1`  `email.2` ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

Where `person` is the name of the input field and `email` is the key

Comment: Thanks for an answer. How would the rules look exactly for `items[]`?

Comment: What are the fields that you are trying to validate inside `items`? Replace `person` with `items` and validate the corresponding fields.

Comment: I'm just assigning the name `items[]` to every input field. This generates the following array `items[0 => 'example', 1 => 'another example']`

Comment: did the items have the same rules ?

Comment: Try this in the validation `'items.0` and `items.1` - this will give each index its own validation rules. But if the index are being generated on the fly, this could be a problem.

Comment: Read this, it should make things clearer https://mattstauffer.co/blog/form-array-validation-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.2 has an array validation all you need to do is :

In your view assuming that you have an inputs like this :

```
<input type="text" name="example[]" />
<input type="text" name="example[]" />
```

The `[]` are the key for this :)

And in your controller you can just do :

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'example.*' => 'required|email'
]);
```

Comment: I'm running Laravel 5. Already tried this to no avail. Guess I will have to change the field names..

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'items' => 'required|array',
    'items.*.title' => 'required',
]);
```